# Accessing local drives in Matlab from command line when using Citric receiver

Tags: matlab, citrix, citrix-access-gateway

I am using Matlab 2018a  within the Citrix receiver. That means, I run the Citrix receiver and it runs Matlab on a server. From this Matlab instance, I can access my local drive, in fact if I click "open" then the window below appears, and I can open any file I want on my local pc. But what if I want to access my local files from command line in my Matlab command window or in a Matlab scripts? I tried:

```
dos('cd \\ALBERTO-PC\C:')
```

I get:

```
'\\ALBERTO-PC\C:' 
CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.
```

I tried

```
dos('pushd  \\ALBERTO-PC\C:')
```

I get:

```
The network name cannot be found. Other ideas?
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to map the UNC drive to a local drive and then use the mapped drive through the mapping

Comment: Follow ups aren't considered an answer, use the comment feature instead.

Comment: I don't have 50 points and can't comment.  This isn't a follow up but an idea to a solution

Comment: I am confused, I said I am running Matlab in Citrix, i.e. I am running it remotely on a server, that is the idea. So I am trying from Matlab to access my local folder, which is a UNC drive for the server.

Comment: on the server computer - map the UNC drive (your local drive) to a drive on the server through file explorer.  Then you can run it easily from matlab

Comment: Ok Maybe I did not make it clear: I do not have access to the server computer! IT people at my university have access and they said they are not gonna change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can access you local C drive via explorer using what is called Client Drive Mapping. You can access those via a UNC path as well as `\\CLIENT\C$` `\\CLIENT\D$` etc. Do not use the client's hostname but use the hardcoded CLIENT name.